# How to ensure code consistency between production and model development environment?

Tags: python, deployment, pyspark

I'm building a serverless application to make some predictions. 
The simple archtecture is exemplified bellow:

```
RAW Data -> Feature extractor -> Model Prediction -> Many consumers
         |
         v
    Persistence
```

Both feature extractor and model prediction are built with AWS Lambda. Also, simutaneously when sending the data to the feature extractor the raw input is saved in a bucket in s3.

When we have to develop a new model we build the following pipeline:

```
RAW Data -> Feature extractor -> Model Prediction -> Many consumers
         |
         v
    Persistence
         |
         v
   New Feature  -> Model Training and testing processes -> New Model
    Extractor
```

The issue is that in the new model pipeline we usually have to produce features from millions of old records. We would like to both be able to reproduce the features used in the prediction at the moment of the request and test new features extracted from the raw data.

When using a simple lambda function is wasy to make some raw python scripts that take about one second to extract features but when try to reproduce it to 1 million of stored records it is impossible. To do that we currently have some Pyspark scripts to proccess all the old and new features to build a new model, but in this case we have always two copies of the code, one in raw python and another one for pyspark.

I would like to know if it is possible to have some consistency between the two versions of the feature extractor, with any technology. I know its possible to have a bunch of test ensuring that both codes produce the same effects but every new feature has to be implemented in the two versions which delay a lot our deployment process.

I think I should expect some kind of desing pattern for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure I am understanding your problem, Let me summary your problem.

There are two pipelines, the first one is used in production for customers, the second one is used for developers to use new feature extractor to build a new model. If the new model performance is better than the production’s model in the first pipeline. Then the first pipeline’s model and feature extractor could be replaced by with the second pipeline’s. The question is how to easily deploy new model and new feature extract to the production.
In your case, maintaining two different programming language versions is very hard because of

1. It needs extra effort to convert one version to another.
2. It also needs the effort to test two version has the same logic without any big side effect.

To avoid that disadvantage, we’d better keep only one version for feature extractor (either raw python or pyspark). In this way, we don’t need to consider the version transforming. Here I choose python as a feature extractor version.

So next problem is how we handle use python lambda to process 1 million of stored records.

It is impossible if we just use the lambda function because we know that the limitation of max execution time for lambda function is 15 minutes. To remove the limit, we could introduce aws step function.

**AWS Step Functions** is service that allows you to coordinate multiple AWS services into serverless workflows. And the Workflows are made up of a series of steps, with the output of one step acting as input into the next. Those small steps could be running in AWS Lambda or Amazon ECS.

So in the second pipeline, I would like to replace new feature extractor with an aws step function. This mark function could have 3 steps.

- Step1: call s3 list objects. Run new feature extractor on the objects, and trigger Model Training and testing processes with new features. and this step output is marker from s3 list objects call. Which will be passed to step 2.
- Step2: check if there are more objects unprocessed by checking marker is empty or not. Go to step 1 if the marker is not null. Otherwise, go to step 3.
- Step3: done.